# Rewriting url's with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite page URL's with .htaccess.
I would like to transform links like this (mysite.com/page.php -> mysite.com/page)

This is the code which I've used in previous sites with the same requirements

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond /%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/$ /$1.php
```

But when I try to access mysite.com/page it leeds to a 404 page where as mysite.com/page.php will show the page.

Can anyone explain if I have missed a setting somewhere? I have placed the .htaccess file in the site root dir and the permissions are set as 644.

Comment: Tried removing ```/``` at the beginning of RewriteCond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` which by the way you have an unneeded `/` there, I suggest you to use `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php`, here is an example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## To internally redirect /anything to /anything.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Additionally on your rule you have `/$` which would again cause you trouble as you want to catch `/page`.

You could have made it `/?` to make the `/` optional.

Your `.htaccess` fixed should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-\s]+)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```